# I want to show facebook profile images of my followers in my comments

Tags: php, facebook, curl

For that purpose I used two methods but neither is working.
For Method 1 I downloaded three files:

1. base_facebook.php
2. facebook.php
3. fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

**Method 1**

```
   include ('facebook.php');
   $facebook = new facebook('API','SECRET');
   $fbid = $facebook->getUser(); 

   echo $fbid; // when i echo this it always show 0; even the followers are logedin or logedout
   echo "<div class='' id=\"user-icon\"><img src=\"'https://graph.facebook.com/{'.$fbid.'}/picture{?type=small}'\"  /></div>";
```

**Method 2**

```
class sfFacebookPhoto{
   private $useragent = 'Loximi sfFacebookPhoto PHP5 (curl)';
   private $curl = null;
   private $response_meta_info = array();
   private $header = array(
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
      "Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
      "Connection: close"
 );
 public function __construct() {
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'shutdown'));
 }
/**
 * Get the real url for picture to use after
 */
public function getRealUrl($photoLink) {
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $photoLink);
    //        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    //this assumes your code is into a class method, and uses $this->readHeader as the callback //function
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(&$this, 'readHeader'));
    $response = curl_exec($this->curl);
    if (!curl_errno($this->curl)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($this->curl);
        var_dump($info);
        if ($info["http_code"] == 302) {
            $headers = $this->getHeaders();
            if (isset($headers['fileUrl'])) {
                return $headers['fileUrl'];
            }
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
/**
 * Download facebook user photo
 * 
 */
  public function download($fileName) {
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $fileName);
      curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      $response = curl_exec($this->curl);
      $return = false;
      if (!curl_errno($this->curl)) {
            $parts = explode('.', $fileName);
            $ext = array_pop($parts);
            $return = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/tmp/' . uniqid('fbphoto') . '.' . $ext;
            file_put_contents($return, $response);
       }
       return $return;
     }
    /**
    * CURL callback function for reading and processing headers
    * Override this for your needs
    *
    * @param object $ch
    * @param string $header
    * @return integer
    */
    private function readHeader($ch, $header) {
     //extracting example data: filename from header field Content-Disposition
      $filename = $this->extractCustomHeader('Location: ', '\n', $header);
      if ($filename) {
          $this->response_meta_info['fileUrl'] = trim($filename);
      }
      return strlen($header);        
    }
    private function extractCustomHeader($start, $end, $header) {
       $pattern = '/' . $start . '(.*?)' . $end . '/';
       if (preg_match($pattern, $header, $result)) {
           return $result[1];
       } else {
          return false;
       }
   }
   public function getHeaders() {
       return $this->response_meta_info;
   }
   /**
   * Cleanup resources
   */
   public function shutdown() {
       if ($this->curl) {
          curl_close($this->curl);
       }
   }
}
```

I saved the above class as curl.php.

```
   require_once 'curl.php';
   $photo="https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=".$session['access_token'];
   $sample = new sfFacebookPhoto;
   $thephotoURL=$sample->getRealUrl($photo);
   echo $thephotoURL;                        
   // but here echo is not showing anything no-error, no-exception, no-output.
   echo "<div id=\"user-icon\"><img src=\"$thephotoURL\"  /></div>";
```

As you can see I want to display images of Facebook users in my comments.
  As in Wordpress or Joomla when a Facebook user comments, their Facebook profile image shows with comments. My website is not using Wordpress or Joomla.
  It's PHP based, I created it myself.
  I used Avatars code which is working fine if any Wordpress user comments on my website. His/her image shows but not Facebook user's.

I am using this code for Wordpress Avatars which is working fine:

```
$hash = md5( strtolower( trim( $row['email'] ) ) );
$default_usr = urlencode( 'http://www.kingofdevelopers.com/images/user-icon.png'); 
echo "<div class='default-user' id=\"user-icon\"><img src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar /$hash.'.jpg?s=45&d=$default_usr'\"  /></div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook already has an easier way to do this.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198/

http://www.ruhanirabin.com/easy-steps-to-facebook-connect-comment-box-how-to/

Comment: The main documentation for this is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/